# Ошибка при выполнении before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Есть две модели: `User` (`has_many :shipments`) и `Shipment` (`belongs_to :user`). Все работает, вроде бы, нормально, - `user_id` добавляется к `Shipment` при создании, но при добавлении в модель `Shipment` `before_action :require_same_user` представление этой модели начинает выдавать ошибку:

> undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

В строке `if current_user != @shipment.user`, хотя `@shipment.user` задан в действии `create`. Чего я недопонимаю?

Контроллер `Shipment`:

```
def create
    @shipment = Shipment.new(shipment_params)
    @shipment.user = current_user
    if @shipment.save
      redirect_to shipment_path(@shipment)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @shipment = Shipment.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

    def shipment_params
      params.require(:shipment).permit(:name, :adress, :user_id)
    end

    def require_same_user
      if current_user != @shipment.user
        flash[:alert] = "Доступ к данной директории ограничен."
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вызываете метод `require_same_user()` до вызова методов `create()` и `show()`, поэтому `@shipment` оказывается не инициализированная, так как её значение устанавливается внутри `create()` и `show()`. Поэтому в методе `require_same_user()` переменная `@shipment` принимает значение `nil`.

Перенесите проверку внутрь методов `create()` и `show()`, после того, как вам становится доступно значение `@shipment`.

Comment: ...или инициализируйте `@shipment` в **ещё более раннем** `before_action`.